# Query Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

```
function get_subject_by_id($subject_id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE id=" . $subject_id ." ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    // REMEMBER:
    // if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false
    if ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        return $subject;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Could you please add echo $query; after the last $query .= statement  and let us see that?  I suspect your $subject_id is blank.

Comment: ...and don't use "SELECT *".

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is just silly

Comment: Also, see about PHP's deprecated mysql_ API, sql injection, and prepared statements.

Comment: @Strawberry Presumably if OP is selecting by ID, then ordering would do nothing as one would rxpect to get back a single result. Still, at the same time LIMIT would also make sense for the same reason. Still, I doubt OP is currently creating the next big web application which would take over the world, but probably learning the ropes in PHP and MYSQL, thus the above seems adequate for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be looking at what your passing into `$subject_id`.

Please please please don't use `SELECT *`. Even if you want all of the columns, write them out. If your tables change and get more columns added then your pulling along more data.

Comment: i substituted an int to see if it's my variable that im passing is bad, it worked then I scanned if there are any mistakes i really couldn't find any so I passed in the same variable again and it worked this time.. really weird.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace all the query thing by this:

> $query = "
>     SELECT *
>     FROM subjects
>     WHERE id = $subject_id
>     LIMIT 1";

Comment: And that would help how or why? Please include reasoning, not just code. And as a separate note, it would not really help, as it would do exactly the same as now, i.e., if the one OP has fails, then this one would fail, too.

Comment: My guess is that the id line is wrong. Some simple quotes are missing :
$query .= "WHERE id='" . $subject_id ."' ";
But, to avoid such problem, I was thinking it would be a good idea to directly put all the instruction in the string. It's maybe not the error, but this can still help.

Comment: @Strawberry However, it is not an answer to OP's question. It is not even an answer, it is what a comment would be if *Isuka* had the rep to write a comment. A suggested answer should, you know, _answer_ the question.

Comment: @Vld Well, Isuka has been a member for 8 days, they have a rep of 11 and they're trying to help. Let's cut them a little slack.

Comment: Well, thanks for the advices. I'll do better on next posts in order to answer the best way.